# continuous periodic function on R

Tags: analysis, continuity

Is a continuous , periodic function on R differentiable ? 
I know that a periodic continuous function is uniformly continuous. Also I'm familiar with Weierstrass function but I don't know it is periodic or not. Can you please help me giving counterexample or a proof if true.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\sin x|$ is periodic, continuous and is not differentiable at $x=n\,\pi$, $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take any continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$, you can use it to construct a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Obviously, not all continuous functions from an interval to $\mathbb R$ are differentiable, so your answer should be no.

To be sure the answer is no, you can look at the function $|\sin x|$.